# Ajax Load Into <div> with child window scrolls to top of webpage

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, load, window.parent

Here is my dilemma, I am calling my external pages via ajax into a `<div>`, within the `<div>` I have links that callback to the parent window which triggers the ajax load event for the next page. My problem is the call back brings the website to the top of the page. Here is the code;

Parent Window:

```
function Display_Load() {
            $("#loading").fadeIn(900,0);
            $("#loading").html("<img src='<?php echo $reg->get ('rel_addr'); ?>img/load.gif' height='50' width='50' />"); return false;
        }
        function Hide_Load() {
            $('#midback').fadeIn('slow');
            $("#loading").fadeOut('slow');
        }
        function loadContent(page) {
            var param = "";
            if (page) { param = page; } else { param='home'; }
            Display_Load();
            $('#midback').fadeOut('slow', function() { 
            $(this).load("<?php echo $reg->get ('rel_addr'); ?>"+param+".php",
            Hide_Load()); return false; 
        });
```

Child Window Code:

```
<span id="events" class="more">more events...</span> 
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.more').click(function() {
                    var params = $(this).attr("id");
                    window.parent.loadContent(params);
                }); return false;
            });
```

I would also like to animate the height of the `<div>` (close it then reopen it to correct height of new page) as well, first I would like to get this out of the way however.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your click on the child to:

```
$('.more').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // . . .
    return false;
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

The problem is when you click on the *more* class, you are likely appending a *#* to the end of your URL. This causes the page to jump up to the top. Per the documentation, the preventDefault will stop this from happening. For good measure, also return false from the *click* function.

Comment: Just attempted it, and it still jumps to the top of the page.

Comment: I highly doubt e.preventDefault() stopped the remainder of your code from executing. Did you copy my code exactly? The // . . . comment was meant to indicate the remainder of your code. How did you debug? Can you get an alert to fire after the e.preventDefault()?

Comment: Sorry Louis, I just double checked it and I had an error in my code, I was trying a different load method. As I added your code it worked through the remainder of the code, but it didnt change the outcome. It still jumps to top of screen.

Comment: It might be somewhere else in your code then. The same principle applies: Anywhere you have the potential to change the URL (even to http://yoursite.com/#) you need to prevent the default. Also, why do you have PHP in your JS?

Comment: It is within a .php file, just getting the relative address of the site, kinda a stupid habit I guess. I do not know where the # is happening since the actual click is a <span> tag not an actual href. I tried it in the loadContent() on the main page and it didn't go past the preventDefault() I will try it again however.